# microsoft graph api, how to access mails from a mailbox in which shared mailboxes are attached

Tags: api, graph, shared

microsoft graph api, how to access mails from a mailbox in which shared mailboxes are attached

1. New Regular Mailbox created
2. shared mailboxes are associated
3. using graph API want to fetch emails from the associated shared mailbox.

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to access each shared mailbox separately. Mailboxes are treated just like user accounts, so you can access them using their email address at the user endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@contoso.com/messages`.